# URL share passing parameters

Tags: wordpress, url, share

I did spend more than 2 hours trying to find an easy answer to this but unfortunately I could not.

The scenario of the problem:

1. A user browses to [ulan.be](http://ulan.be), selects 3 parameters and continues.
2. The page redirects him to something like [here](http://ulan.be/ist2/?id=45&ref_id=59aadd492d3ad&ezfc_element%5B834%5D=1&ezfc_element%5B836%5D=1&ezfc_element%5B838%5D=9500&ezfc_element%5B875%5D=9&ezfc_element%5B876%5D=28&ezfc_element%5B877%5D=26&ezfc_element%5B879%5D=4).
3. The user wants to share this with another user via a social share button (say email or Whatsapp) but the URL gets cut and parameters don't get passed.

Basically what I need is a Wordpress plugin or a basic JS code to enable a "copy paste of the address bar" to the 2<sup>nd</sup> user.

Any help is appreciated - thank you.

Comment: What's the code that performs the functions above?

Comment: it is a 3rd party plugin called ezfc form calculator. it forwards the field values to the next page with these parameters and i want the 2nd user to browse the same page with same parameters.

Comment: Some formatting issues + minor semantics

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this simple logic:

```js
var sel = document.querySelector("#ddlViewBy");
var input = document.querySelector("input#location");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var param1 = '';
var param2 = '';

button.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
   param1 = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
   param2 = input.value;
   //Just to check the value
   //alert(param1 + ", " + param2);
});

//Then reconstruct your URL bar with the params above
/**
  *  orig_url = window.location.href;
  *  window.location.href = orig_url + '?city=' + param1 + '&zip=' + param2 
  *
**/
```

```html
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Location" />

<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

I hope this helps.